# Value + Text for generated SelectList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with a generated droplist, it shows up like this:

```
<select id="selIntervalStartTime" name="selIntervalStartTime"><option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option><option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option><option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option><option>System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem</option></select>
```

In my code I have:

```
List<SelectListItem> si = new List<SelectListItem>();

for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
{
      si.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
}


return View("ScheduleEdit", 
          new ScheduleEditViewModel 
           { 
               selIntervalStartTime = new SelectList(si)
           });
```

How do I fix this so i.ToString() shows up as value and text?

/M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<int> si = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
{
      si.Add(i);
}


return View("ScheduleEdit", 
          new ScheduleEditViewModel 
           { 
               selIntervalStartTime = new SelectList(si)
           });
```

or

```
List<SelectListItem> si = new List<SelectListItem>();

for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
{
      si.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() });
}


return View("ScheduleEdit", 
          new ScheduleEditViewModel 
           { 
               selIntervalStartTime = new SelectList(si,"Text","Value")
           });
```

Answer (score 3):

All is good just need 2 more parameters:

```
   selIntervalStartTime = new SelectList(si,"Text", "Value");
```